# How to append Month and Year from Datetime column in C# datatable with other column using linq

Tags: c#, linq

For example I have a payment collection table as follows:

| Division | Collection Date | Emp | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DivA | 01/04/2021 | ABC | 10000 |
| DivB | 01/04/2021 | XYZ | 12000 |
| DivC | 07/04/2021 | ABC | 12000 |
| DivD | 07/05/2021 | ABC | 9000 |

I want a data in the following format using linq

| DIVision | ABC-04 | XYZ-04 | ABC-05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

I have tried following linq on datatable

```
string[] ColumnFields = { "Collection Date", "Emp" }
DataTable _SourceTable = GetCollectionDataTable();

var ColList = (from x in _SourceTable.AsEnumerable()
               select new
                      {
                          Name = ColumnFields.Select(n => x.Field<object>(n))
                                             .Aggregate((a, b) => a += Separator + b.ToString())
                      }).Distinct()
                        .OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
```

Please guide

Comment: please put your table structure and result in correct display format. How your data is related to your result ?

Comment: Have you heard about PIVOT queries?

Comment: Yes but I want to do pivoting on in-memory collection